# Upload Image issue in Xcode and ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using follwing Code as i am new to xcode please tell me how to send image with the data. The data is posting perfectly to the server. Just add the code so that i can send the image to the Server:

```
- (IBAction)senddatatophp:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Working insert button");

    NSString *did = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"deviceID"];
    NSString *deviceTokenStr = [[[[did description]
                                  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"<" withString: @""]
                                 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @">" withString: @""]
                                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];

    //NSLog(@"%@", deviceTokenStr);

    NSData *getimgdata1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_frontimg.image, 1);
    NSLog(@"%@", getimgdata1);


    NSString *name=@"Admin";
    NSString *lastname=@"panel";

    NSString *tag       =   @"watchlist";
    NSString *gcmid     =   deviceTokenStr;
    NSString *brand     =   textbox1.text;
    NSString *model     =   textbox2.text;
    NSString *year      =   textbox3.text;
    NSString *condition =   textbox4.text;
    NSString *box       =   textbox5.text;
    NSString *warranty  =   textbox6.text;
    //NSString *front_img =   _path1;
    //NSString *back_img  =   _path2;
    //NSString *side_img  =   _path3;

    NSString *sendData = @"name=";
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", name]];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&lastname="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", lastname]];



    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&tag="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tag]];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&gcmid="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", gcmid]];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&brand="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", brand]];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&model="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", model]];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&condition="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", condition]];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&year="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", year]];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&box="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", box]];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&warranty="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", warranty]];
    /*
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&front_img="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", front_img]];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&back_img="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", back_img]];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:@"&side_img="];
    sendData = [sendData stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", side_img]];
    */


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.onlinestoresolution.net/demo/buymywatch/buymywatch/index.php"]];

    [request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

    //Here you send your data
    [request setHTTPBody:[sendData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *stringReply = (NSString *)[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    _SendWatchId = stringReply;

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", stringReply);

    }
    else
    {
        //The response is in data
        NSLog(@"Success: %@", stringReply);
    }


}
```

Comment: have you passed NSData *getimgdata1 ? in you request

Comment: yesi have passed the img byte code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for sending image file. write down this code, once you have posted your text data on server.

```
 UIImage *img=self.imgView.image;
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@upload.php",@"http://localhost:8888/ImageUploadiOS/"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test%d.png\"\r\n",self.fileNum] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Image Return String: %@", returnString);
self.fileNum++;
UIAlertView *alertUpload=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"DemoApp" message:@"Image Uploaded On Server" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alertUpload show];
```

php code for stroing image data on server is below.

```
    <?php
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

echo "file=".$file; //is empty, but shouldn't

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo $file;
}
else {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

don't forget to change url of request.
for sending multiple image code is

```
        //image1
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile1\"; filename=\"testing1.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//end here image1



//image2
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile2\"; filename=\"testing2.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData2]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//end here image2
```

Php code for handling muliple images at once is

```
      <?php
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$file1 = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile1']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file1;

echo "file=".$file1; //is empty, but shouldn't

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile1']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
    //echo $file;
    //echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]) . '!';
    echo 'file1 moved';
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}



$file2 = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile2']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file2;

echo "file=".$file2; //is empty, but shouldn't

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile2']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))
{
    //echo $file;
    //echo 'Hello ' . htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]) . '!';
    echo 'file2 moved';
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
```

?>

Comment: server response will be assigned into data. instead of deleage method receive response data.

Comment: It is giving me the error "Use of undeclaredidentifier 'data'"

Comment: i have modified my answer, re-check pls

Comment: Thanks THe error is remove just one error is left filenum. Please tell me what is that

Comment: fileNum is int type value, for unique image file name. every time we post image from app to on server. like test1.png, test2.png etc.

Comment: make sure $uploaddir = 'uploads/';   uploads directory exists at same level means your .php file and uploads folder having same parent folder. another point, upolads folder having read/write permission.

Comment: It is there and i got file=Resource id #6error error

Comment: try, remove code of sending text data. just try with sending image data only. and check if this is working or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65519/discussion-between-shesh-nath-and-sandeep-kumar).

Comment: i would suggest, use two request separately. one for sending text data and one for sending image data. since image data is king of multi-part data. and text data is kind of form data.

Comment: Can you provide me the code that i need to put after sending my text.

Comment: i have modified my answer.

Comment: ya sure i will check that

Comment: I am trying to implement the above code but still image is not uploaded

Comment: Your code is working fine please tell me how can send 3 images using the above code. I do not want any redundancy in the code

Comment: if you don't want to use threading, i have modiefied my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not that any of this has any sense but if you wish to send both the string data and the image data you need to append the data together. To do so it is easiest to use a mutable version of the `NSData`:

```
NSData *input1;
NSData *input2;
NSMutableData *output;

output = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithData:input1];
[output appendData:input2];
```

Then `input1` is your string data and `input2` your image data (or vice versa) and your `output` is what you use in the body.

And the first thing you might want to look in is to send the request asynchronously since you are dealing with the large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

```
// add image data
NSData *getimgdata1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_frontimg.image, 1);
if (getimgdata1) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:getimgdata1];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

refer to this [NSData and Uploading Images via POST in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042360/nsdata-and-uploading-images-via-post-in-ios)