# Unable to uploading Images on server in IOS

Tags: php, ios, web-services, image-uploading

I am not able to upload images on php server from my IOS app.

Here is my code..

```
NSString *urlString = @"My URl";

 NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

// setting up the request object now

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;

 [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    // NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------147378098314876653456641449";
    NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";

    NSString* FileParamConstant = @"profileimage";


    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",BoundaryConstant];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        ///---

    // post body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    // add params (all params are strings)
    for (NSString *param in dicSubmit)
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [dicSubmit objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }


    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imgprofile.image, 0.0f);

    if (imageData)
    {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"editprofileimage1.png\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }



    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // set the content-length
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[body length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    // set URL
    // [SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
    [request setURL:requestURL];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: may be you have not define "POST" method of request type

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103728/upload-image-issue-in-xcode-and-ios/27103919#27103919

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to using AFNetworking

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"]];

        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.m_clientPhoto.image);

        NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dict setValue:self.nameTextField.text forKey:@"name"];
            [dict setValue:self.countryCode1 forKey:@"countrycode"];
            [dict setValue:self.phone1 forKey:@"phone"];

        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

        AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"rest.of.url" parameters:dict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {


            [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"img" fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

        } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);


        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);

            }];

    [op start];
```