# Post Image Using multiPart To URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, multipartform-data

Actually i have json parameter

```
[dictionary setObject:_dateOfBirth.text  forKey:@"birth_date"];
    [dictionary setObject:_tfCountry.text  forKey:@"country"];
    [dictionary setObject:_tfEmail.text  forKey:@"email"];
    [dictionary setObject:@""  forKey:@"fromLogin"];
    [dictionary setObject:@1  forKey:@"gender"];
    [dictionary setObject:@"signup"  forKey:@"methodName"];
    [dictionary setObject:_tfContact.text  forKey:@"mobile"];
    [dictionary setObject:_tfName.text  forKey:@"name"];
    [dictionary setObject:_tfNickName.text  forKey:@"nickname"];
    [dictionary setObject:_tfPassword.text  forKey:@"password"];
    [dictionary setObject:_tfPinCode.text  forKey:@"pincode"];
```

There Is also a Image that i have to set profile_pic as a Key.
Now I have Converted all Parameter as a data and POst That Data lie This

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    // this is your service request url

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://proteen2.inexture.com/webservice"]];

    // set the content as format

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    [request setHTTPBody: jsonData];

    // this is your response type

    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;

    // send the synchronous connection

    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    // here add your server response NSJSONSerialization

    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];
```

It's Works fine for Text, Now how to attach Image to that Parameter, I am only aware with Multi Part but not getting that Point. Please Help

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042360/nsdata-and-uploading-images-via-post-in-ios

Comment: What is Boundary? if i convert image into NSdata the How To add That data into reference to That Parameter to Particular key. I m confused

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage many thing here, like set `boundry` append image data etc etc.

You should use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to make is very simple. Download from github and just drag and drop library to your project and import `AFNetworking.h` in your class and then you can do something like,

```
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:@"urlstring" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

    //Append image here for example;

    UIImage *img = tempImageView.image;
    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.5);

    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imgData name:@"imagename/serversideparameter" fileName:@"imagename" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];


} error:nil];

//Send this request to server. Something like,

NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc]initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

[[manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    if (!error) {

        NSLog(@"success!!");

        NSLog(@"here is the response : %@",responseObject);
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"Error Occured : %@",error.localizedDescription);
    }

}]resume];
```

You shouldn't use `NSUrlConnection` because it is deprecated now. It's better to use `NSUrlSession` which i have used in answer via `AFNetworking`.

If you don't want to use `AFNetworking` then refer [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250475/post-multipart-form-data-with-objective-c). It have great explanation step by step in answer.